# haproxy logs in a kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes, containers, haproxy, systemd, rsyslog

I'm trying to run haproxy in a container deployed by kubernetes but it won't start from my entry script, when I logged into the container and tried to start it by hand I get:

`[ALERT] 021/125902 (998) : sendto logger #1 failed: No such file or directory (errno=2)`

The haproxy config I have for logging is:

```
log /dev/log    local2 debug
```

And in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` I have:

`local2.*                       /etc/haproxy/logs/haproxy.log`

I have `/etc/haproxy` as a shared volume mount in the container. So I want to send the logs to a file. The problem I have is that `systemd-journald` is not running in the container (from google searches seems like getting it to run is not straight forward). The error that haproxy is complained about is because there is no
`/dev/log` in the container. So How do I get haproxy logs from my container?

Comment: Are you able to access `/etc/haproxy/logs/haproxy.log` when you `exec` into the container? If you could not `exec` as you are not able to start the container, then create an empty data file at that location with read-write access.

Comment: as `systemd` is not in the container, you should be able to control the start of haproxy using the `entrypoint` or `cmd` with all the volumes mounted correctly (and `/etc/haproxy/logs/haproxy.log` empty file created) with the read-write permissions.

Comment: Yes as I said in the question I can exec into it and as I said the log file is accessible via a
 shared mount from within the container, the problem is I can not redirect it to systemd,
as systemd is not supported in the container. No problem starting haproxy when I
remove the log option that redirects to systemd. It seems from my research that your
only option is to log to stdout in raw mode. This is not a haproxy specific issue, it is
a systemd support in a container issue.

Comment: could you explain why you would need `systemd` for logging? Are you using `journald`?

Comment: It's systemd-journald is the problem